# Missing Hot Network Questions

Tags: bug, hot-questions, sidebar

While browsing, I noticed that the **Hot Network Questions** suddenly disappeared. I thought it was just an internet problem, so I reloaded, but it is still missing, even from other tabs with different tags in each. I even tried hard reset, but still missing

[image]

Did I hide it accidentally, or is it really missing? I noticed it immediately because I always look there for interesting topics

**EDIT:**

It is now visible again, but I'm still baffled as to what happened why it disappeared

Comment: [Oh the irony :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNfs6.png)

Comment: Oh for a second I got excited that they got rid of it. I find it so distracting that the only way I can actually use SO is to set up ad blocking rules on every site to hide it. On every computer...